# Controversial logic problem from brilliant. Misinterpreted logic or flawed question?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, puzzle

You are offered two cupcakes. One is poisoned and the other is safe to eat.

You happen to be in a village full of knights (who always tell the truth) and knaves (who always lie), but you can't tell which is which by their appearance.

You ask one of them, "Which cupcake is safe to eat?" To this he makes the following two statements,

"If I were a knave, I'd say the one on the right."
"But I'd say the one on the left, if I were a knight."
Which cupcake is safe to eat?

Assumption: The person you ask knows which cupcake is which.

This problem appears on brilliant in the practice section (truth tellers and liars level 3 challenges) and it's causing a bit of a heated discussion. The answer is supposedly the cupcake on the left. Is this question flawed or are people misinterpreting the logic?

Comment: What are your thoughts?  Do you find something controversial in the official answer?

Comment: Well maybe I have misinterpreted the logic of "if a then b" but here is my reasoning. If we suppose the good cupcake is on the right then it can't be a knight saying this. If the person saying this is a knave then they are lying about saying that they would tell it's the one on the right so they would say it's the one on the left (but because that's what a knave would say then the good cupcake is the one on the right.) If we suppose it's the one on the left then a knight saying this would be consistent but a knave can't say this statement because that would imply he would say it's the one

Comment: on the left but we know that's the truth. It seems to me there is no way to tell in this situation but i don't know maybe i'm wrong, that's why i am asking in the first place

Comment: Presumably the argument is that, for a knave, the proposition "Were I a knight I'd say $X$" is always true, since the premise is false.   Thus the knave could never make a statement of that form, so the speaker must be a knight.    I would agree with someone who said it was phrased at least somewhat ambiguiusly.

Comment: To be clear: had the speaker said "A knave would say Right, a knight would say Left" then you could not decide, since, if the ground truth were Right, both of those claims would be lies, consistent with the speaker being a knave.

Comment: @lulu: I’d agree with that analysis if the statement were *… if I am a knight’; in that case the antecedent is definitely false. The use of the subjunctive changes things: it’s arguable that it makes *I am a knight* a stipulated hypothesis, so that in the context of the sentence it has truth value $\top$. (Of course for those of us to whom the traditional subjunctive comes naturally, *if I were an X* implies that I am **not** an X, so that a knight could not make the second statement, and it’s not clear to me just how that affects a knave’s statements. Propositional logic is too blunt a tool.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott  Oh, I am not defending the phrasing of the question, nor even the argument I gave.  I am just reverse engineering from the official answer.  I can't see any other way to justify declaring that the correct answer is Left.  To be clear:  were I in this situation, there is no chance that I would eat either of the cupcakes based on this information.

Comment: @lulu: Fair enough; that was also how I concluded that they were justifying it. I definitely consider it a defective question, though, and I’m with you on declining the cupcakes!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In mathematical logic, the statement "If $A$, then $B$" means a very precise thing, in a way that it is not always interpreted as in everyday conversation. It means no more and no less than the following statement: "It is not the case that $A$ is true and $B$ is false".

For instance, "If $2+2=5$, then $2+2=6$" is an example of a true implication. We're only committing to the second half of the statement *if the first half is true*, which it's not - so the statement remains true! An "if" statement is only false when the first part is true but the second part is false. See [the Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Material_conditional) for a more in-depth treatment.

With that cleared up, let's take a look at this problem, and name our mystery person P. In fact, we only need to look at the second sentence.

> P: "But I'd say the one on the left, if I were a knight."

They're saying "If (P is a knight), then (P would answer "the one on the left" to your question)".

When is this statement false? It's false when (P is a knight) is true, but (P would answer "the one on the left" to your question) is false. So this will be false only in those scenarios where P is a knight and would tell you the safe cupcake is on the right.

What can we conclude from this? Well, P can't be a knave, because then the statement would be false, but it can only be false when P is a knight! So P is a knight, and therefore the statement is true. So, we can conclude that P really *would* tell you "the one on the left", and because they're a knight, that answer would be the correct one.

Comment: Fascinating logic!